# How to change label of an ext3 partition under Windows 7 or Tomato Linux?

Tags: windows-7, linux, router, filesystems

I have several hard drives hooked up to a router running Tomato and shared over the network. I have mapped the drives to everyone's computer as M:, T:, etc. which also shows the label as if it were a local drive. The drives were formatted as ext3 back when I set the network, however, I gave them really horrible names such as bigfatty, twoteebee and the color of the drive, which just confuses everybody. I would like to rename them so that people can see which is for what purpose.

I've installed the free Paragon ExtFS which let's me read/write to the drives, but changing the label always gives an error. There are a number of other software, but looking through their info pages, none mention the ability to rename partitions. EaseUS Partition Master Free Edition is what I originally used to format the drives, but there is no option to rename there, either, unless I re-format.

Is there a way under Windows 7 x64 to do this? Or, alternately, could I somehow do it via telenetting in to Tomato? I'm using [Tomato by Shibby - K26USB-1.28.RT-MIPSR1-117-AIO](http://tomato.groov.pl/download/K26/build5x-117-EN/tomato-K26USB-1.28.RT-MIPSR1-117-AIO.trx) which has kernel 2.6 but beyond that no clue what's installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't probably change label from client computers, you have to do it in Tomato.

Try telnet or ssh into busybox running in Tomato and run something like

`# fdisk -l` which should show you all devices with labels and then change label by

`# e2label device newLabel` or `tune2fs -L newLabel device`

Comment: Weird but both of those call tune2fs. Your 2nd example is what worked.